# Android: Spinner autorefreshing itself - How to?

Tags: android, refresh, spinner

I have made the following Android widget:

A spinner "Location" populated from the sqlite table "Location", which pops an EditText dialog on a long touch, and which saves the EditText' valie to the "Location" table, on dismissing the popup dialog.

Now I would like to have the spinner autorefresh itself with the new information I have just entered, and have no idea how to proceed - here is my current code

```
    chooseLocation = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.choose_location);
    //set long clicks to add an item
    chooseLocation.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
    //just an EditText dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(MyActivity.this);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.add_location)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            if (input.getText().toString().equals("") == false) {
                //save EditText to database
                db.open();
                db.insertLocation(input.getText().toString());
                db.close();
            }
            dialog.cancel();
        }})
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }})
    .show();
    return true;
}});
    //Binding the database data and the spinner
    Cursor locations = db.getLocations();
    startManagingCursor(locations);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, locations,  
                                    new String[] { "_name"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1}); 
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
    chooseLocation.setAdapter(adapter1); 
    mb.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not so good in SQLLite, but i think , when you insert the new value into the table Location, you can send another request to select from location , and display it in your Spinner , or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to tell the Adapter to refresh itself after you set it on the Spinner with a call to

```
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I tried both and had little success. I ended up calling onCreate() on the activity, as I have 5 spinners, 4 of which update each other, and little else in the activity. Kind of a sledgehammer solution, still would like a better one.